# ASUS GL753VD-GC003 Backlight Keyboard Colors

Tags: keyboard, brightness, asus, colors, backlight

I bought an ASUS GL753VD-GC003 and everything works perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04, except some function keys like controlling screen brightness, keyboard backlight brightness, airplane mode, and a few others.

These do not bother me much but what I would love would be to be able to change the keyboard light color since this laptop allows for RGB colors. Right now the color is red and I cannot change it. I think this is because it has something to do with the BIOS as far as I've read online.

The laptop is a bargain for its price and the fact that Ubuntu runs without a problem on this system, but such small features like controlling keyboard backlight would be cool to have on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to change the backlight (yet) but if you update to the latest kernel (I have 4.12) the function keys will work (you have to press FN though). Hope it partially helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I upgraded the kernel to 4.12.10 and most FN keys work now. Except for the brightness of the keyboard. I tried msi-keyboard-gui-linux-x64 to see if maybe it could work to change the keyboard color but does not. Btw for those interested, I upgraded the kernel via Ukuu - super simple little app.